# Can I access a path without a basepath?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a swagger 2.0 file (open.yml), wherein, I have defined a basepath : `/abc`

But, I don't require basepath while accessing /users only but for rest I require the basepath .i.e presently

Url: `http://IP/abc/users`
But, for only path users I want:
Url : `http://IP/users`

I went through their official docs of swagger 2.0- swagger.io/docs/specification

---

**Update -1:**

Consider the following file:

```
swagger: '2.0'  
info:
  title: "OpenGame"
  version: "3.1"
host: "localhost:2102"  
basePath: /abc
produces:
  - text/plain
  - application/json

paths:
  /users:
    get:
      operationId: specification.users.user
      summary: "Returns the version of QuantumLeap."
      tags:
        - meta
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successful response."
          schema:
...

 /control:
    post:
      operationId: specification.config.config
      summary: "Control"
      description: ""
      parameters:
          type: number
          description: "number"
      tags:
        - meta
```

Thus, when I type `http://localhost:2102/abc/users` on browser it works properly.

But, I want to use - `http://localhost:2102/users` instead of the above `/abc/users`

Is there any way to do so this??

Also, I want other paths for eg: `/control` here to be served using basepath when fired i.e `http://localhost:2102/abc/control`

Comment: Add more details. Links are not always useful and can be intermittent..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "access a path" - access how, from where? Do you mean you are writing an API definition where one path has the `/abc` prefix but other paths don't have this prefix? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to remove the basePath and add "/abc" prefix to all other resources other than users. Alternatively it may be appropriate to model these APIs in two separate Swagger files